# Cant pull/push git from Android studio 4.0 canary

Tags: android, git

Each time I attempt to pull a repo from bit bucket, I keep getting the error

```
 Failed to start Git process User Authentication Token not found
```

I have tried resetting the windows credential, uninstalling and reinstalling both git and Android Studio, as I think there is a compatibility issue with Android studio 4.0 and my pc which uses windows 10.

Any ideas?

Comment: Same issue here with Android Studio 4.0 Canary 7 on Windows 10.

Comment: There is already an issue tracked for this: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/145767113

Answer (score 16):

The following helped me:

1. From the directory of the previous version `C:\Users\(Your user)\.AndroidStudio3.(version)\config`(I checked on 3.5 and 3.6 versions)  copy the **user.token** file.
2. Paste it into `C:\Users\(Your user)\.AndroidStudioPreview4.0\config`
3. Launch any git operation requiring authorization (push/pull), in the window that appears, enter your authorization data.

Comment: Mac users, copy the file `~/Library/Preferences/AndroidStudio3.5/user.token` to `~/Library/Preferences/AndroidStudioPreview4.0/`

Answer (score 6):

Here's the workaround from [Google's issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/145767113).

1. Close the IDE.
2. Remove [settings](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519-Directories-used-by-the-IDE-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs) for Android Studio 4.0 or copy them somewhere else.
3. Install [3.6 RC 1](https://developer.android.com/studio/archive).
4. Run it and perform any Git operation in the IDE.
5. Close 3.6 and open 4.0 again importing settings from the previous version.

Answer (score 1):

You are not alone with it.

Have the same issue on Linux (Android Studio 4.0 Canary 5).
I could not "*Enable Version Control Integration*" in the new project.
I tried to login on GitHub in settings (*Version Control* -> *GitHub*), I put my token and then seen the success... but when I closed the settings window and reopen it I seen the message "Missing access token".

**EDIT: 2019-12-21**

I want to make you happy.
I found the page with previous versions of Android Studio.
**Git works in *Android Studio 4.0 Canary 4***, just remove your version and download it on the link below.

https://developer.android.com/studio/archive

Comment: I have Android Studio 4.0 Canary 9. I still get the error Failed to start Git process User Authentication Token not found.

Answer (score -5):

If you've created two-factor authentication, you can't log in like this, so try something like this:

```
git remote -v 
git remote remove origin 
git remote add origin git@github.com:user/repo.git
```

visit here to get token: https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/creating-a-personal-access-token-for-the-command-line

Comment: I have not created any two factor authentication, and this happens with all repositories including libraries from github etc.

Comment: this is not the case for the question @artspb anwers works for me